# Intercept all function calls in javascript

Tags: javascript, electron, hook, v8

What i will like to do is intercept all function calls in javascript, either if they are created by `new Function` , or `function`.

In other words to maybe do a Proxy for all functions that will be created. To execute some code before the function initial code.

So my questions are:

1. is there a way to do this ?
2. is there a way to change Function.prototype ? It is build-in with configurable:false. Can that be changed.
3. I am trying to do this in electron, so i can change flags for V8, enable Experiments
4. Can this done with a native function enabled with `--allow_natives_syntax` flag ?
5. Is there a way to change internal [[Call]] ?

I know about all the reasons why i should not do this. I am only interested in a way that can be done.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is there a way to do this?

No.

> 2. is there a way to change Function.prototype ? It is build-in with configurable:false. Can that be changed?

No.

> 4. Can this done with a native function enabled with --allow_natives_syntax flag ?

No.

> 5. Is there a way to change internal [[Call]] ?

No.

If you're just interested in tracing function calls, you can use V8's existing `--trace` flag. It's not possible to replicate that functionality in JavaScript (otherwise that flag wouldn't exist).